# meta.yaml: how to require one from a list of packages

Tags: python, conda, requirements, conda-build

Is there a way to code a requirements section in a meta.yaml file where any one package from a list of choices will satisfy the requirement? This is where different packages provide the same needed capability and there is no reason to specify a particular choice.

In my case the conda svn package and the conga-forge subversion package provide the same tool and either is fine, but an analogous case would be where either PIL or Pillow would be required so I want to have something like:

```
requirements:
  run:
    - python>=3.7
    - pil or pillow
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing to this is [*build variants*](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/variants.html). This would entail issuing a separate build for each variant. Setting aside that the example here is contrived (`pil` is outdated and only available for Python 2.7 on Conda), but it'd be something

**conda_build_config.yaml**

```
pil_variant:
  - pil
  - pillow
```

**meta.yaml**

```yaml
requirements:
  run:
    - python>=3.7
    - {{ pil_variant }}
```